Difference between PageSpeed ​Insights and Web Vitals browser plug-in
I measure the LCP indicator of the website page https://anc.ua/item/estezifin-krem-1--tuba-15-g-1045278
PageSpeed ​​Insights: 
LCP 4+
Web Vitals browser plug-in: 
LCP 2 or less
All measurements show such a gap.
Why is the LCP difference so significant when comparing Pagespeed Insights and the Web Vitals plugin?

Page Speed insights simulates an average mobile device with an average network connection in its servers.
The plugin uses your own browser on your machine, which could be a lot faster than the device and network connection Page Speed Insights simulates.
